# I don't have a mac but I need to deploy to a flutter app to a physical IOS device

Tags: flutter

Would it be possible to build the app through a platform like code magic **and then** through Xcode on the VM, deploy it to my physical ios device? I am not looking to emulate on a virtual machine, I simply want to see the app on my physical device and I do not have a mac.

Comment: You can't deploy to your apple device without an apple device to talk debug protocol to it, and a developer account with Apple (free or paid)

Answer (score -1):

The [codemagic](https://codemagic.io/start/) is great and very useful for such cases as this, you can build your flutter project to ios just from the website, and it gives you 500 free minutes every month to use.